# Export multi different attachments with multi different file formats into a single PDF file

Tags: php

we allow customers to attach their invoices to our site in any format they want e.g. PDF, JPG, PNG, XLS, DOC, TIFF, BMP, etc.. We do however have a need to export/download these attachments in a PDF format on an as needed basis

If you have any suggestion or third party script. please provides us url.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion, first you need to convert to all these formats to .pdf to be able to go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for valuable suggestion... Have you any suggestion like third party...

Comment: well i have searched for it but the thing is most of them are paid .. so you need to deal with it else you can first convert the uploaded files to pdf using php by checking extension like for images you will have different code whereas different logic for documents like xls ..

Comment: Okay, I will work on your suggestion. Thanks